# How to keep a custom widget common across more than one screen in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am making a flutter application in which I need two put a widget which is common for more than one screen. Here is the code of build method of screen one

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: app_color,
        body: _isLoading == false ? Stack(


          new Container(//used for whole screen ),
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    bottom: 0,
              //a bottom tab like which is common across screens
            ),

          ],
        )
      :
          //code to show progress indicator while loading data in background 
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                    child:Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: 50,
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    )
                ),
                Positioned(
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    bottom: 0,
                    //keep this to show bottom tab while loading 
                ),
              ],
            )


    );
  }
```

Above code has a positioned widget at the bottom of the screen which I want to keep common across more than one screen? How can I achieve it? I have knowledge of android and in that case I can achieve using fragment transaction but here I have to keep the bottom positioned widget across all screen and the problem with this is that after changing screen bottom position widget disappears for some time but I want that bottom widget to be kept static and change only the screen not bottom positioned widget

Answer (score 6):

One way to accomplish that is to customize the builder, in the MaterialApp widget.

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      home: TestPage(),
      initialRoute: "/test",
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              child!,
              Positioned(
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    bottom: 0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
      routes: routes(context),
    );
  }
}
```

That will render the widget in all screens, and the transition animation between screens will not mess it up, and you can freely use other Scaffolds in your pages as you normally would.

Comment: I have been looking for some similar solution to allow for bottom ads to not reload on every screen. Didn't know the builder could be used for that

Answer (score 2):

You can do one of two things

### 1- create a custom widget

create a file called `common_view.dart` and add the view to it

```java
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CommonBottom extends StatelessWidget {
  CommonBottom();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      .......
    );
  }

}
```

Then use it in all your pages as `CommonBottom()`

### 2- create your app as a single page app

create a stateful widget for every page you need and render it inside your page wrapping it with a visibility widget.

Answer (score 0):

well it won't be static for all pages unless you implemented it in each page and in order to do that you need to import the file where that class exist and use it directly.

```
import 'packages/mycommonclass.dart';
```

and then place it at the same place as the other pages.

Comment: during page transitions the bottom bar is hidden for some duration.How to avoid that ?