# Prevent Flutter widget tree rerendering on mob store update and performance improvement

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobx

I have been trying to build an app using flutter and I am having a hard time figuring out certain concepts in flutter. I am hoping to find some answers here.

Preface:
App dependencies: **flutter_mobx,auto_route,get_it**.

I am building an app where I need to show some alerts. I have created a Flutter page (`AlertsScreen`) which is subscribed to *mobx* **alerts_store**. So whenever I try to push an alert to the **alerts_store** the snackbar should popup. Something similar to which I have been doing in React web.

App repo link: https://github.com/ganeshrvel/open_cloud_encryptor/tree/new-router-logic

Questions:

1. How do I mount a common widget like `AlertsScreen()` which will be rendered across the app.
   Earlier I used to do something like this:

app.dart ([Github link](https://github.com/ganeshrvel/open_cloud_encryptor/blob/4d1f9918d5705f686f3a378ba42a92072964c8c4/lib/features/app/ui/pages/app.dart#L43))

```
MaterialApp(
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget widget) {
    setErrorBuilder();
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: widget,
        ),
        AlertsScreen(),
      ],
    );
  },
  title: 'App name',
  onGenerateRoute: Router.onGenerateRoute,
  initialRoute: Router.splashScreen,
  navigatorKey: Router.navigator.key,
),
```

But then whenever I try to render Flushbar or any other item inside AlertsScreen which requires `context` it throws an error:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception:
>   Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a
>   Navigator. The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator
>   must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.

Flushbar example code:

```
Flushbar(title: 'title',message: 'body',duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),).show(context);
```

How do I mount a common widget like `AlertsScreen` across the app and which will be always visible for any sort of activity?

2) This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55675611/1317099) from stackoverflow suggests to make a CommonWidget stateless widget and use it wherever it has to be rendered.
So taking cues from the above stackoverflow answer I modified my code like this:

common_widget.dart ([Github link](https://github.com/ganeshrvel/open_cloud_encryptor/blob/new-router-logic/lib/widgets/common_widget/common_widget.dart))

```
class CommonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
 final Widget child;

const CommonWidget({
    @required this.child,
  });

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: child,
        ),
        AlertsScreen(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

home.dart ([Github link](https://github.com/ganeshrvel/open_cloud_encryptor/blob/new-router-logic/lib/features/home/ui/pages/home.dart))

```
class _HomeScreenState extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: CommonWidget(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Is this the right way to do it?

3) I use **flutter_mobx** as the store for `AlertsScreen`. Since I have used CommonWidget in multiple screens for displaying `AlertsScreen`, whenever I update the store the AlertsScreen gets rebuilt multiple time. How do I prevent this? How do I make sure that `AlertsScreen` widget is only rerendered in the current screen and prevent it from rebuilding everywhere else while updating the store?

Current the workaround is something like this:

alerts.dart ([Github Link](https://github.com/ganeshrvel/open_cloud_encryptor/blob/new-router-logic/lib/features/alerts/ui/pages/alerts.dart))

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _alertsStore ??= Provider.of<AlertsStore>(context);
    _disposers ??= [
      reaction(
        (_) => _alertsStore.alertsList.iterator,
        (alertsList) {
          if (ModalRoute.of(context).isCurrent) { // Check whether current screen is rendered 
            buildSnackbar();
          }
        },
      ),
    ];
  }
```

Is there any better way to do this?